# how to put a filter on magento collection on a computed column value

Tags: magento, collections

How to add filter to collection to a computed column?

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns("sum(col1,col2) as distance ");
```

distance is computed from addition of col1 and col2

now how to place a check on distance<10 and reduce the number of items in the collection.

```
->addFieldToFilter('distance',array('gt'=>10)) didn't work
```

I have replaced a complex mathematical function with sum for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use having clause `$collection->getSelect()->having('distance >10')` directly in your query

take a look at this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection

Comment: Having will not work as below query don't work in mysql. "select somecol as aliascol where aliascol>5"

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/how-to-add-dynamic-field-in-magento-collection take look at this question

Comment: having('distance >10') worked but not with pager. I have removed the pager for the time being. will have to go through that class functions in order to understand how to write it properly.